# php md5_file function with gif file?

Tags: php, image, dynamic, md5, gif

I discovered that when I use php `md5_file` function to get the `md5 checksum` of the image, the checksum is different everytime.

Is it the gif image or is the `md5_file()` function that is dynamic?

Comment: The MD5 value will always be the same if the file is the same. Maybe show some code if the problem persists

Comment: Just md5_file("path/to.file");

Comment: No, the value shouldn't change, unless the file changes.

Comment: i cant reproduce this. are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the file contents change this is impossible

```
md5_file("path/file");
```

If `file` stays the same the output will be the same hash every time